# Always real valued complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{a,b,c,d\}\to\mathbb{C}$ defined by $$f(z)=\dfrac{z}{z-a}-
\left(\dfrac{z}{z-b}+\dfrac{z}{z-c}+\dfrac{z}{z-d}\right).$$
I,m trying to find the relationship between $a,b,c,d$ so that $f$ always assumes only real values.

How can I find such a condition?
Thank you.

Comment: $a=b=c=d=0$ ? $$$$

Comment: Put $z = x+ iy$, evaluate $f(z)$. Now you can find the relation from the equation $\Im(f(z)) = 0$

Comment: Do you mean real values for real arguments? Otherwise f can only be constant.

Comment: $z$ was arbitrary.

Comment: @MartinR: Thank you for your reply. Can you explain it bit more.

Comment: Your function is analytic on its domain. It’s well-known that an analytic function that takes only real values must be constant. Why? Analytic functions are open mappings, i.e. must map open subsets of the domain to open subsets of the target space.

Comment: @Lubin: Thank you for your helpful comment. I got it. If you can please post this as an answer. I would like to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is analytic on its domain. It’s well-known that an analytic function that takes only real values must be constant. Why? Nonconstant analytic functions are open mappings, i.e. must map open subsets of the domain to open subsets of the target space.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

**Step-1** Simply the expression- $\frac{z}{z-a}=1+\frac{a}{z-a}$. Do it for all.

**Step-2** Make the denominator real- $\frac{1}{z-a}=\frac{\bar{z}-\bar{a}}{\|z-a\|^2}$. Do it for all.

**Step-3** Do $f(z)-\bar{f(z)}$ and find when it is zero.

Comment: In Step-1, it should be ${z \over z-a}$

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: Resulting expression wont be independent from $z$.

Comment: But you will find it as the following form $\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_i(z-\bar{z})$ where $a_i$s are real numbers.